# Django: Defining more than one signal receiver for a model and same signal

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, signals

Is it possible to define more than one signal receiver for a model A and it's `pre_save` signal?

```
@receiver(pre_save, A):
def func1():
    ...

@receiver(pre_save, A)
def func2():
    ...
```

I'm going to define a receiver for `pre_save` and Model A in my app, but would like to care if that is already being defined by any other existing apps.

Using Django 1.4.

Comment: More than one? sure, isn't that the purpose of signals?

Comment: I want to know, what if there is one already defined and my definition will override that?

Comment: Thanks! I'd consider that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receivers of signals do not override one another. They all get called.

[The documentation is here.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals)